# WebStorm mocha test 'sh' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: windows, bash, exec, sh, webstorm

I'm trying to run a mocha test for my node.js code which runs the following line:

```
exec(`sh ${scriptFile}`);
```

When I run it from the command line (Git Bash) using `npm test`, it passes. However, when I run it from WebStorm I get the following error:

```
'sh' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I feel like I'm probably missing some WebStorm setting, but I can't figure out what it is. Any ideas?

P.S. I'm on Windows.

Answer (score 3):

For those who are using phpStorm on Windows and come here by Google

Install Git on your machine. Go to `Settings/Terminal` and set `shell path` to `C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe`

Also add `C:\Program Files\Git\bin` to your PATH in environment variables.

Answer (score 1):

Git Bash implements a *nix-esque shell simulating bash which can parse your command. Webstorm appears to be trying to execute your command in either powershell or cmd, which do not support sh syntax.

> Open the Terminal page of the Settings/Preferences dialog, and configure the Shell path field as follows:
>
> `"[path to the git installation]\bin\sh.exe" -login -i`

This will probably be `"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe" -login -i`

Source: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2017.1/working-with-embedded-local-terminal.html

Comment: Tried it but it doesn't work. The page says that I should be able to run git commands after that, but that doesn't work either. I get `$ git status` `sh: git: command not found`

Comment: Update: this solution allows me to run sh commands from the local terminal, but the javascript code still fails.

Comment: Could you run an experiment and `echo $PATH` from normal Git Bash and from webstorm terminal? I suspect that they may be different

Comment: It prints the same thing. However, when I do `exec('echo $PATH')` it just prints `$PATH`. Looks like the shell being SPAWNED by Webstorm doesn't have it's environment set correctly.

Comment: If it printed '$PATH' your quoting is just preventing variable expansion actually. Not having a path set would have printed you a newline.